# Short Circuit Protection Circuits

Tags: short-circuit

Please forgive me for my ignorance but when it comes to Li-Po I am really not willing to take any risks.

I plan to implement a short circuit protection circuit on my PCB which is basically holding MCU, motor drivers, other ADC's and communication IC's. I am using a 6S lipo to power the full operation. My PCB is working fine. But given that during a short circuit there will be 100+ Amps of current flowing, I need some ideas on which circuits/IC's will help me design an efficient protection circuitry.

Comment: Maybe a simple fuse?

Comment: Does the 6S pack have any current limiting circuitry built-in to it?

Comment: You could also buy cells that have built-in in current limiters. Or make your own e.g.: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm3641.pdf Most [removable] cell-phone batteries have something like that inside: 2FETs + protection IC on a tiny PCB. For your 6S you'll need a different IC, so shop around.

Comment: @mkeith No it doesn't have an in-built circuitry

Comment: @icy although a fuse might help i was hoping of something which I dont have to keep on checking in the long run.

Comment: Probably this: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/slusa08a/slusa08a.pdf

Comment: If you have a LiPo pack with current capability of more than one or two amps, it _needs_ to have the protection before there's any wires going elsewhere, or you are inviting explosions at some point in the future. There's a reason a car has a main fuse very close to the battery before anything else (with the possible exception of the starter relay in some cases, but you need to be aware of the level of testing and experience that goes into that bit).

Comment: Two things: First, you need to protect the battery pack. That is outside the scope of this question (but check out the link from @RespawnedFluff). Second, a fuse should be fine to protect the PCB (it should only blow in the case that there is a fault). Fuses have a maximum interrupt rating. Make sure the maximum interrupt rating is higher than the battery pack short circuit current. Tiny PCB fuses may arc over after opening if the fault current is very high. Fuse closer to battery = good. You can also put a PCB fuse on the board in case it is powered from another source besides the battery.

Comment: @mkeith -- Excellent points (thanks for contributing!). One very small correction: arcing is a function of voltage, not current. You need a voltage sufficient to cause the isolation barrier to breakdown. Otherwise, the current won't flow, no matter how high it was prior to interrupt. In the case presented here, he's ok with even SMT PCB fuses because the voltage is so low.

Comment: @DrFriedParts, dielectric failure of air occurs due to high e-field. E-field is caused by potential difference. Potential difference can arise from interrupting current when there is inductance in the circuit. And there is always some inductance in the circuit.

Comment: In any event, fuses DO have maximum interrupt ratings. The interrupt rating for small SMT fuses will probably be less than the available short-circuit current from the LiPo stack. If not then it is OK.

Comment: @mkeith -- Yes of course the parasitic inductance will convert the current interruption to voltage, but in this situation it is unlikely to be sufficient. The fiberglass substrate of the PCB (FR4) breaksdown at more than 20kV/mm and air is about 2000kV/m. Even at 100A interrupted in 1ms (very conservative for this scenario) you would need on the order of Henrys!

Comment: @DrFriedParts, I am too lazy to double-check your math right now. FR4 was never my concern. Air will ionize long before FR4 suffers breakdown. But as I said, fuses do have maximum interrupt ratings. I checked one example on digikey, the littelfuse 0603. It's interrupt rating is 50A. I got the impression from the OP saying "hudreds of Amps" that maybe this was a large capacity battery pack. All I am really saying is that the OP should select a fuse with adequate interrupt rating.

Comment: @mkeith -- Absolutely! I completely agree with you and, as noted initially, find all of your commentary extremely helpful. I was really just pointing out your subsequent statement: "dielectric failure..occurs due to high e-field". Cheers.